# What is wrong with my Python program using the find command?

Tags: python

I am trying to type in a list of names and then determine which ones contain the letter "e" or the letter "E" but it always just returns as 0. Can somebody tell me why?

```
def count_contain_e():

    num_names = int(input("How many names are you going to enter: "))
    count = 0

    for i in range(num_names):
        name = input("Enter middle name: ")
    if (name.find("e") >= 0):
        count += 1

    return count

def main():
    num_w_e = count_contain_e()
    print "The number of middle names with the letter e is " + str(num_w_e)

main()
```

Comment: Only the last entered name is processed, previous are overwritten. Additionally, uppercase "E" won't be found.

Comment: off topic: consider using `if 'e' in name:` ... that's a more natural looking test

Comment: don't you have an indentation problem for your `if` statement ?

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with indentation. The if should be on the same level as `name` assignment (1 more tab than currently).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the identation of `if` statement.
What you need is insert the `if` inside the `for` in order to analyze all the names that you input, like this:

```
for i in range(num_names):
        name = input("Enter middle name: ")
        if (name.find("e") >= 0):
            count += 1
```

Right now in the `if` you are only analyzing the last name because in the loop you are rewriting the variable all the time before to do the `find` method.

And for sure, if you want to count the capital letter too, you need to add it to the if condition, if not the program only counts the lower letter.